# Как скопировать формулы и стили всех ячеек при работе с xls?

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

Работаю с библиотеками xlrd, xlwt, xlutils. Так как невозможно вносить изменения в старый проект, создаю новый. Если просто переписывать значения, понятное дело, что стили и формулы не копируются. С помощью модуля xlutils.copy мне удалось скопировать все стили, но что делать с формулами? как их скопировать?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Let me google it for you ...*
[python excel copy formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20excel%20copy%20formula)

Первой же ссылкой идет:
[Get formula from Excel cell with python xlrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690423/get-formula-from-excel-cell-with-python-xlrd)
.